# Local Conda installation failing due to permissions on shared hosting

Tags: symlink, conda, miniconda

Is there a way to create a local installation of conda in a completely portable way that will handle all dependencies not currently linkable on the system?

I had thought I could create an isolated, local installation. But it turns out you seem to need links to system packages belonging to root. I think this is the essence of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640056/do-conda-environments-have-access-to-root-environment-system-packages), which remains unanswered.

I've been using conda quite a bit with non-root installs on servers. Right now, I'm trying to install it on a Bluehost shared server. They have recently changed the ssh shell to a jailshell that does not allow linking to system packages. I did not realize this would be an obstacle. However...

```
[/home7/arielbal/miniconda3] >>> /home7/arielbal/test/conda
PREFIX=/home7/arielbal/test/conda
installing: python-3.6.1-2 ...
tar: bin/2to3: Cannot create symlink to `2to3-3.6': Permission denied
tar: bin/idle3: Cannot create symlink to `idle3.6': Permission denied
tar: bin/pydoc: Cannot create symlink to `pydoc3.6': Permission denied
tar: bin/pydoc3: Cannot create symlink to `pydoc3.6': Permission denied
tar: bin/python: Cannot create symlink to `python3.6': Permission denied
tar: bin/python3: Cannot create symlink to `python3.6': Permission denied
tar: bin/python3-config: Cannot create symlink to `python3.6m-config': Permission denied
tar: bin/python3.6-config: Cannot create symlink to `python3.6m-config': Permission denied
tar: bin/pyvenv: Cannot create symlink to `pyvenv-3.6': Permission denied
tar: lib/libpython3.6m.so: Cannot create symlink to `libpython3.6m.so.1.0': Permission denied
tar: share/man/man1/python3.1: Cannot create symlink to `python3.6.1': Permission denied
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Bluehost does allow compiling (unlike greengeeks.com), so I actually went through the trouble of compiling the dependencies to get the initial miniconda install. I was eventually able to get that to work. But when I tried to install further packages, I again ran into permissions/linking issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think after assigning all the priviledges to the current login use in terminal you would be able to install miniconda. Please let me know if you trind something different and worked!

You can find the miniconda repository here: https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/