# How to add a path like "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages" to sys.path permanently?

Tags: python, conda, sys.path

I am studying Pytorch, and I use Windows and Jupyter notebook.

When I try to import some modules like gym or cv2 on Pytorch Kernel, there are errors like 'no modules names gym'.

When I run sys.path on Pytorch there is no path "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions", which is there on Python3 kernel.

So I used sys.path.append to add this path and I could import the modules successfully.

But is there a way to add this path permanently to my sys.path on Pytorch?
Or should I type sys.path.append every time I run the different code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions` is a path from a virtualenv `pytorch`. [You need to `activate` it in the Anaconda prompt before running a kernel](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script):

```
C:\> C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\Scripts\activate

(pytorch) C:\>
```

If you need to run something (semi-)automatically in this environment, see [How to make batch files run in anaconda prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305569/how-to-make-batch-files-run-in-anaconda-prompt).

[If you need `jupyter` in this environment, you'll need to install corresponding `conda` packages into it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640056/do-conda-environments-have-access-to-root-environment-system-packages)